# wxpython installed with wxmac homebrew formula: how to get working?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, osx-lion, homebrew

I installed the wxmac (wx) homebrew formular with the `--python` and the `--devel` option to get python and 64bit support. Now if I try to run the [getting started example](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#A_First_Application%3a_.22Hello.2C_World.22) from the wxPyWiki, I get this error:

```
This program needs access to the screen
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you
are logged in the main display of your Mac.
```

The way I try to run the program is by simply typing `python wx.py` in iTerm2, and I get that response.

What is the problem and how do I get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the 64-bit Mac Python build from python.org called "Python 2.7.3 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer". Then go to wxPython's website and download the development cocoa build as that's the only 64-bit wxPython available for Mac. Then when they're both installed, it should work.

Comment: To be fair, what homebrew does when I install python and wxmac is exactly that. It downloads those packages from the respective site, and then it builds them on my computer with some options that make it all work. What would be interesting is, if there is some options that must be set for everything to work correctly (which it doesn't now) that homebrew doesn't set, and if so, which are they?

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so I can't really say. I was going off my knowledge of what I've gleaned from being on the wxPython-users mailing list for the last few years. You should ask over there. I'm sure they could tell you.

Comment: I'll try asking on the mailing list. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Trying to build wxPython on the mac from source is very aggravating. Use the binaries as suggested in the above answer.